# Контроль изменений объекта с помощью CSS

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Всем привет. На сайте есть изменяющийся под нужды пользователя блок. (тыкнул на кнопку, размеры должны измениться, внешний вид тоже) если делать это с помощью JS:

```html
function resize680(){ 
  $('.cell').addClass('ches680'); 
  $('.ches').addClass('ches680');
  $('.Table').css({'width':'0','height':'0'}); 
  $('.Table').css({'width': '680px', 'height': '680px', 'margin':'0 auto'}); 
  .... 
  .... 
} 
function resize1000(){ 
  $('.ches').addClass('ches1000');
  $('.Table').css({'width':'0','height':'0'}); 
  $('.Table').css({'width': '1000px', 'height': '1000px', 'margin':'0 auto'}); 
  .... 
  .... 
}
```

Все работает стабильно, но требуется сделать все с помощью CSS и минимальным участием JS. Вопрос: существует ли  в CSS конструкция аналогичная:

```html
switch (activeClass) {
case Size680:
    style1{
    ...
    }
    style2{
    ....
    }
    break;
case Size1000:
    style1{
    ...
    }
    style2{
    ....
    }
    break;
}
```

Таким образом я с помощью JS меняю только активный класс и для него будут подтягиваться нужные стили. Не кидайте в меня камнями пожалуйста ели это бредовая идея. Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Уточняю задачу:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На этом изображении блок по умолчанию. Выделенные зеленым блоки это правила, которые меняются в зависимости от размера(я предполагаю, что возможно заказчик захочет еще что-то добавить).

[image]

Тут изображение с блоком меньшего размера. Я не мастер верстки, так что выглядит это не очень. Таких размеров около 5-ти. Правила для всех разные.

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/media , http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media - оно?

Comment: Если блок один, то для него (с соответствующим классом) задаются стили через css. Получается минимальный js: ты кликаешь, в родительском блоке добавляется-удаляется класс, а значит  и всё, что ниже по дом, тоже меняется визуально. Просто нужно стилей добавить.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , media, на сколько я понял не подходит, так как у меня размер экрана не меняется, а меняется лишь только отдельный блок.

Comment: @Boroda95 значит я не вчитался... просто увидел resize680 и resize1000 и подумал..... тогда как предлагают выше: делаешь классы в css с нужными атрибутами... а в функциях лишь присваиваешь/убираешь эти классы из блока

Comment: @VostokSisters, Я кажется понимаю, что Вы имеете в виду, но до конца сообразить не могу. Пожалуй я поправлю вопрос, наверное это внесет ясность.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предлагаю типа такого:
[codepen](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/oZmGmM)

```js
$blockOutter = document.querySelector('.blockOutter');

function changeClass() {
  $blockOutter.classList.toggle("ches");
};

$blockOutter.addEventListener('click', changeClass);
```

```css
.blockOutter {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.blockOutter .blockInner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.blockOutter.ches {
  background-color: blue;
}

.blockOutter.ches .blockInner {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockOutter">
  <div class="blockInner"></div>
</div>
```

Посмотри на js. Мы добавляем класс к родителю и как только это мы сделали, браузер запускает перерасчет стилей и встречает уже заранее заданные стили для этого класса. Таким образом мы ссылаемся на стили для внутренних элементов через заданный класс для родителя, ведь стили для элемента, у которого есть класс, имеют больший вес. Поэтому применяются конкретно они заместо стандартных.
На этот счет советую поискать про то, какие селекторы какой вес имеют для отрисовки их браузером. Запомнить их сложно, поэтому ты сам видишь, что я тоже плаваю тут, но держать в голове и знать как оно работает, необходимо в любом случае.

В данном примере я просто меняю цвет бекграунда, но ты можешь любые стили переписать в "классовом" селекторе, какие тебе нужны.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую воплотить это, опишусь о результате.